# Playing subsequent movies in one MPMoviePlayerViewController

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

I am having a difficulty with the MPMoviePlayViewController.
I insatiate the controller, assign the url and show the player using:

```
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:[appDelegate movieController]];
```

Then when the movie finished I dismiss it:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];    
[self dismissMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated];
```

The movie player is alloc in my AppDelegate. 
There are some other listeners on MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification. This is for the case where there might e.g. only be audio and it shows a play/pause button and counters in table cells.

The problem is that when I load a second movie in the same MPMovieViewController, it appears fine but the controls are not working correctly. They are work as long as they are visible, but as soon as they disappear there is no may of getting them back and therefore to dismiss the movie player.Sometimes closing and opening the App works, but sometimes it doesn't and I need to 'kill' the App in order to be able to start again.

Is there a way to play subsequent video's in the MoviePlayer while the controls still work?
Any suggestions how to 'reset' the Player in a way that I can prevent the other listeners from given a DEALLOC as they are listening for the action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you dont need to dismiss the player you just need to set the new url... or maybe I missunderstood your problem...

Try adding this to your setup movie player controller

```
moviePlayerController.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Comment: That is right, but there seems a problem that the view doesn't register any interaction with the player to show/hide the controls. Hence once the controls are hidden they will not return on tapping the screen and it is impossible to return to the previous view.
I am now implementing a fix for this by setting a flag when a video stops playing to release the player on the next request and re-instantiate it. Not the most elegant way but it gets around the problem.

Comment: so your controls are not being shown once they dismiss? are your controls  customized?

Comment: Yes. The firs time you play them it is fine, but then after hitting 'done' or the movie is finished, and loading a new movie, once they disappear (after 4second?) there is no way to get them back. No customization, just a MPMoviePlayerViewController.

Comment: Sorry Calleth, I loved it by releasing and recreating the player. Not the most elegant, but it worked and allowed me to submit the update.